# Update default state based on the property

Tags: unit-testing, vuejs2, vue-component

I am working on a button component that also receives a default state value.

```
export default {
    props: {
        defaultState: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        }
    },

    data() {
        return {
            currentState: this.defaultState
        }
    },

    computed: {
        isActive() {
            return this.currentState;
        },
    }
    ...
}
```

And i can am using it like `<button :defaultState="true"/>`.

Now the problem is when I am trying to write a test for my component I always gets the **false** (which is default value) value of `currentState` after using the `wrapper.setProps({ defaultState: true })` that should be **true**

```
it.only ('should work with dynamic state change', async () => {

    wrapper.setProps({
        defaultState: true
    });

    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();

    // shows the true
    console.log( wrapper.vm.defaultState );

    // should be true but i get false 
    console.log( wrapper.vm.currentState );
});
```

Can anybody please point me to the right direction and what I have missed?

Comment: I also recently had issues with setProps. It would not work and the props would never get the new value. My workaround was to just create the wrapper again with the desired props just for that test case.... not sure, but my be a vtu bug!

Comment: @danroc thank you for your reply, the `watch` property solved my issue. I have used the `beforeEach()` at the very beginning that automatically set wrapper with every test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a better solution for this is to create a computed property. This would eliminate the need for both the data property and the watcher:

```js
export default {
    props: { 
        defaultState: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        }
    },

    computed: {
        currentState() {
            return this.defaultState
        }
    }
}
```

However, if your component is this simple, the computed `currentValue` property is not needed at all! Because all it does it repeat the value of the `defaultState` prop which by itself is already reactive.

So it means you are adding complexity to a component just to make it work for the tests... and the component would work perfectly even if you didn't have this.